# Photons and heat relation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Just thinking over quantum physics for a bit, i was curious about the following:
When a material is heated enough it can emit photons 'think of fires and light bulb'. The question is, can a material be heated significantly more than the ambient temperature without losing or emitting photons ?  (citation please, if the answer is yes)

Comment: Yes, due to Kirchhoff's law the emissivity of a material is the same as its absorptive ratio at the same frequency (for all frequencies). This means that highly reflective materials are also poor emitters. A perfect mirror would therefor not emit any radiation, at all. This is extremely important for the so called antenna temperature, which for clean antenna surfaces can be far below the actual temperature of an antenna structure. Without this it would be very difficult to build well working IR and radio telescopes, since the whole structure would have to be cooled, not just the receiver.

Comment: @CuriousOne Having a perfect mirror The same amount of photons will be er-emitted, but all of them have a redshift. So even a perfect mirror or starts moving or emit photons in IR.

Comment: @HolgerFiedler: Nope. Please read up on the physics of thermal emitters.